# Login loop when switching to Intel drivers using prime-select?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, intel-graphics

I've installed the Nvidia driver (375.66) from the official repos and everything (including switching between intel and nvidia using prime-select) was working fine until one time, I accidentally switched from intel to nvidia and then back to nvidia, without logging out after switching to intel. After this, whenever I try to switch to intel, I get stuck in a log in loop (logs in then returns to login screen) i.e., X keeps failing. What should I do?